# Shell script for file renaming

Tags: linux, wordpress, shell

I have a Linux (Debian) server running a Wordpress site.
My WP site has a theme with a header image called boats.jpg.

I would like to schedule a cron job every hour that executes as shell script that changes the header image. But I am not sure how to write the script.

I have a folder with seven images boats.jpg and boats1.jpg to boats7.jpg.
I would like to do a loop that every hour renames the files so that they one by one are renamed to boats.jpg.
What I mean is that I want to rotate these seven images to be the header image. And the header image is the one that are called boats.jpg.

Can someone give me a hint how to solve this?

Comment: I think you'd be better off modifying the header to select a different image each day than to move around images on your filesystem.

Comment: @b777: Your feedback will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try following. Make file backups and test well before actually executing:

```
#! /bin/bash
while true
do
    for i in "boats1.jpg" "boats2.jpg" "boats3.jpg" "boats4.jpg" "boats5.jpg" "boats6.jpg" "boats7.jpg"
    do
       echo $i  # just to see what will be copied
       cp "$i" boats.jpg   
       sleep 5s  # change to 1h for 1 hour delay
    done
done
```

Output on my system:

```
$ ./boats.sh 
boats1.jpg
boats2.jpg
boats3.jpg
boats4.jpg
boats5.jpg
boats6.jpg
boats7.jpg
boats1.jpg
boats2.jpg
boats3.jpg
boats4.jpg
boats5.jpg
boats6.jpg
boats7.jpg
boats1.jpg
boats2.jpg
boats3.jpg
boats4.jpg
boats5.jpg
boats6.jpg
boats7.jpg
boats1.jpg
boats2.jpg
boats3.jpg
boats4.jpg
boats5.jpg
boats6.jpg
boats7.jpg
...
```

Script can be stopped by control-c.